# What type of connector, adapter or tubing do I need to connect the fridge to the water line?

Tags: refrigerator

I need to know what type of connector, adapter or tubing I need to connect the fridge to the water line with this type of valve: white plastic with a blue shut off valve:

[image: Blue shutoff valve]

(Source: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B00PFTFV8W?pc_redir=T1)

Comment: Why do you want a shutoff valve to your fridge's water/ice maker?

Comment: [relevant?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/58357/how-do-i-tap-into-the-pex-water-supply-line)

Comment: @DanielGriscom so you can replace/repair/move the fridge without turning off the main water shutoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want something like this [Pex 25-Foot Ice Maker Connector](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004CR4OBS), which uses 1/4" compression fittings at each end.

[image]

Except you won't use the compression nut, instead you'll just push the end of the tube into the push connector on the valve.

Comment: When I purchased the connection as shown I came to find out the push connector is 3/8" and the fridge is 1/4". Is there an adapter?

Comment: Probably. You should be able to find something at the local plumbing supply, hardware, or big box store.